# Multiple Wildcards/Filters for SQL

Tags: sql

I am attempting to only retrieve Business Unit specific information from a large datamart, and would like to structure my query to eliminate unrelated DepartmentIDs.

In plainspeak, the end goal is to filter on ALL DepartmentIDs starting with "AN" and ending in 0, P, A, N, R, V, C, L, W, E, or Y.

Currently the query starts with:

```
FROM bbms_tpirc.dbo.LaborDetailByName LaborDetailByName
WHERE (LaborDetailByName.post_year='2016') AND
      (LaborDetailByName.center_id='APEEN') AND
      (LaborDetailByName.loan Like 'AN%')
```

but I am struggling with the next section.

Using another `AND (LaborDetailByName.loan Like '%0', '%P')` etc doesn't return anything in the dataset. Might I be overfiltering, or simply forgetting an argument?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Many of them have regexp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your filter clause

```
(LaborDetailByName.loan Like 'AN%')
```

with

```
(LaborDetailByName.loan Like 'AN%[OPANRVCLWEY]')
```

Comment: Way easier than I was thinking it would be.. thank you!

Comment: Glad that it is helpful to you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server or MySQL, you can use `RIGHT()`:

`AND RIGHT(LaborDetailByName.loan,1) in ('0','P','A','N','R','V','C','L','W','E','Y')`